# Configuring Liberty Profile to use H2 database

Tags: java, jpa, h2, websphere-liberty

I have an embedded H2 database running that I have been connecting to as such:
[Browser H2 interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1iFl.jpg)

This works exactly as desired. I'm using JPA/EJB/JSF to build an EAR that will run on Liberty Profile. I've configured Liberty Profile to work with several different databases in the past, but am having no luck with H2. My server.xml looks like this:

```
<!-- Enable features -->

<featureManager>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.1</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>managedBeans-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxws-2.2</feature>
</featureManager>
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

<library description="XXXX" id="XXXX" name="XXXX">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/XXXX" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>



<dataSource type="javax.sql.DataSource" id="XXXX" jndiName="jdbc/XXXX">
        <jdbcDriver javax.sql.DataSource="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
            <library>
                <fileset caseSensitive="false" dir="${shared.resource.dir}/XXXX"/>
            </library>
        </jdbcDriver>

     <properties password="gg" URL="jdbc:h2:~/XXXX" user="SA" databaseName="XXXXDB"/>
</dataSource>
```

```
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
```

This method never finds the database. I've also tried using `192.168.2.13:8087`, but that gives

```
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: No suitable driver found for http://192.168.2.13:8087 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 8,001
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:603).
```

I've spent a considerable amount of time searching google for the proper configuration, but have been unsuccessful. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps if you post the persistence.xml that OpenJPA requires ...

Comment: For some reason, your database URL is `http://192.168.2.13:8087`. It should be something like `jdbc:h2:~/XXXX`

Comment: This is my persistence.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">
 <persistence-unit name="xxxx-jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/XXXX</jta-data-source>
  ...
  
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Comment: My origin attempt used jdbc:h2:~/XXXX but it would never be found. The 192.168.2.13:8087 was just something I was trying.

Comment: This is the error I get when using jdbc:h2:~/XXXX: [code]Caused by: org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Table "COMPANY" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT COUNT(t0.ID) FROM COMPANY t0 [42102-178] {SELECT COUNT(t0.ID) FROM COMPANY t0} [code=42102, state=42S02]
 at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:219)
 at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.wrap(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:199)
 at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator.access$000(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:59)

Comment: Please post the contents of your persistence.xml file. I believe your last comment is the key to what is going on here.

Answer (score 4):

This is my working h2 configuration in the server.xml of the wlp:

```
<dataSource
    id="mydb"
    jndiName="jdbc/mydb"
    type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <jdbcDriver
        javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
        javax.sql.DataSource="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
        javax.sql.XADataSource="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
        libraryRef="SharedLibrary_H2"/>
    <properties
        URL="jdbc:h2:C:/Apps/db/h2/mydb.db;MV_STORE=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"
        databaseName="MY_DB"
        user="sa"
        password="sa" />
   </dataSource>

<library id="SharedLibrary_H2">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/h2" id="Fileset_H2"/>
</library>
```

The h2.jar must be available at:

```
C:\path\to\wlp\usr\shared\resources\h2\h2-1.4.187.jar
```

In the persistence unit of your peristence.xml:

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/mydb</jta-data-source>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving seems to indicate that OpenJPA can't determine which DBDictionary to use.  When first initiating database connectivity, OpenJPA tries to determine the proper dictionary to use based on the connection's metadata.  In this case, either a connection can't be established to the database (you should be able to verify this with the given url information for your database), or OpenJPA can't determine the database type based on the metadata.  My guess is that it's the latter situation you are running into.

You can bypass this automatic dictionary detection by specifying the dictionary in your persistence.xml file.  Try specifying this property and see what your results are.

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="h2"/>
```

More detailed information can be found here:
http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_dbsetup_dbsupport